# Github Actions trigger when add user to repository

Tags: github, triggers, devops, github-actions

I am m new in GitHub actions, and unfortunately I did not find any info about trigger on adding user to repo.

Is there somethinglike this in GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 2):

The "[Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows)" page does not list indeed anything regarding a new user/collaborator being added to a repository.

As such, this does not appear to be a supported event.

You might consider a [scheduled event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events) to monitor at regular interval a repository, querying the [list of collaborators (GitHub API)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-collaborators), and triggering another job if the number changes.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much!